# Save image in windows phone 8.1 using FileSavePicker

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to save an image using File Save Picker . I am using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150592.aspx) link to save but it is only for text , how I modify it to save an image?

Comment: Do you mean how you could add the option to save a file as .jpg for example?

Comment: You get as a result [StorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) - open a stream for it and then write to that stream. Have you tried something similar? Also are you targetting Silverlight or Runtime?

Comment: Yes I mean how could I add options to save it as png and I am targetting runtime not silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have provided [the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150592.aspx) then I assume that you managed to get *StorageFile* after [Continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614994.aspx) (this is how it works at WP8.1 Runtime).

I also assume that you have a *Stream* with your image or you know how to obtain such a one. Basing on those two, you can save your image in *png* format to a file selected by picker for example like this:

```
public async Task SaveStreamAsync(IRandomAccessStream streamToSave, StorageFile destination)
{
    BitmapDecoder bmpDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(streamToSave);
    PixelDataProvider pixelData = await bmpDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, null, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
    using (var destFileStream = await destination.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
    {
        BitmapEncoder bmpEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, destFileStream);
        uint yourWidthAndOrHeight = 1024;
        bmpEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, yourWidthAndOrHeight, yourWidthAndOrHeight, 300, 300, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
        await bmpEncoder.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Also please remember to `Dispose` your `streamToSave` (and other resources) after finishing working with them.

If you take a look at [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) and [BitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx) classes, then you will see more options including transformation and various properties.

(I've not tested the code above rough, but hopefully it will work fine)

Comment: I have a video in StorgaeFile object. How can I get the first frame from video and display it using BitmapImage to user? I am also saving the video in other folder.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar There is no place in comments to ask/answer such question. It would be better if you have asked simply a new question, post some of your code, mention the research you have done. Currently I don't know, but maybe someone will.

Comment: @Romasz The width and height in setpixeldata method should be get from bmpDecoder.getPixelWidth()/bmpDecoder.getPixelHeight()  or the pixels should be calcaulated manually based on yourWidthAndOrHeight. The above code can sometimes  throw “The buffer allocated is insufficient” exception.

Comment: @MohanRajNK This is only a sample and I assume that the person who uses it knows what height/width to use or how to get it.