# How to save an image in LocalStorage?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I created this image 'my'

```
BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage();
bImage.UriSource = new Uri(muss.Immagine, UriKind.Relative);

Image my = new Image();
my.Source = bImage;
```

I need to save the image in LocalStorage. how could I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving and loading an image from localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158887/saving-and-loading-an-image-from-localstorage)

Comment: I think you may find some help in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24809020/2681948) ot [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25995145/2681948).

Answer (score 0):

`bitmap.Save("C:/Users/folderName/imageName.jpeg");`

This is the best way to store image locally in your folder by bitmap.